# Clicking above or below thumb of scrollbar doesn't scroll

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar, controltemplate

On a default `ScrollBar`, when clicking above or below the `Thumb`, the scrollbar moves in the direction of where you clicked.

I have a custom scrollbar template and this feature doesn't work anymore. I had a look at the [scrollbar reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/Primitives/ScrollBar.cs), but don't seem to find anything that does this. So, how does this work?

Any idea on what I could be missing in my control template?

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
   <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent" Opacity="0.01">
      <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="True" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
         <Track.Thumb>
            <Thumb Style="{StaticResource DefaultVerticalScrollBarThumbStyle}"/>
         </Track.Thumb>
      </Track>
   </Grid>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}" Value="True">
         <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bg" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.01" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
         <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bg" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.9" To="0.01" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
      </DataTrigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for information on control templates, better look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollbar-styles-and-templates) on that rather than reference source, it is easier to read and offers some examples.

The area above and below the thumb of the `ScrollBar` are [`RepeatButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/repeatbutton)s. You have to add them to your `Track` with the `DecreaseRepeatButton` and `IncreaseRepeatButton` properties:

```
<Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="True" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
   <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
      <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
   </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
   <Track.Thumb>
      <Thumb Style="{StaticResource DefaultVerticalScrollBarThumbStyle}"/>
   </Track.Thumb>
   <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
      <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
   </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
</Track>
```

Of course you should style those buttons to fit your design. By the way, the *Up* and *Down* buttons on the `ScrollBar` work the same way, you would add two `RepeatButton`s to your `Grid`, one above the `Track` and one below, but  using the `ScrollBar.LineUpCommand` and `ScrollBar.LineDownCommand`.